# How can a map an asynchronous function over a list?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Obviously, given a list `l` and an function `f` that returns a promise, I could do this:

```
Promise.all(l.map(f));
```

The hard part is, I need to map each element, *in order*.  That is, the mapping of the first element must be resolved before the the next one is even started.  I want to prevent any parallelism.

I have an idea how to do this, which I will give as an answer, but I am not sure it's a good answer.

**Edit:** some people are under the impression that since Javascript is itself single-threaded, parallelism is not possible in Javascript.

Consider the following code:

```
const delay = t => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t));
mapAsync([3000, 2000, 1000], delay).then(n => console.log('beep: ' + n));
```

A naïve implementation of `mapAsync()` would cause "beep" to be printed out once a second for three seconds -- with the numbers in ascending order -- but a *correct* one would space the beeps out increasingly over six seconds, with the number in descending orders.

For a more practical example, imagine a function that invoked `fetch()` and was called on an array of thousands of elements.

**Further Edit:**

*Somebody* didn't believe me, so [here](https://jsfiddle.net/58eqmtng/2/) is the Fiddle.

Comment: But doesn't `Promise.all` groups all promises into a new one which will call `then` when all child promises have finished successfully? And those will come in order already.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer -- perhaps my edit will make clearer what I mean by "in order".

Comment: It seems like you don't know that asynchronous flow doesn't work like you expect...

Comment: Í'll recover my answer tonight, now I need to go somewhere and I've no time to discuss with you your own error.

Comment: Please provide an actual implementation of the *beep* thing which demonstrates your conclusion. Elaborate more on this, because I guess you're mistaken in your reasoning... But I want to be sure instead of guessing it.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer -- I can't resist a challenge.

Comment: I was expecting a runnable code snippet!! Well, I build it myself

Comment: I've created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wm18Lc01/) and I don't get the same output as yours. Maybe you're working on Node?

Comment: Even in node I couldn't get the same *bad* order...

Comment: Fiddle added.  Same behavior.

Comment: So I got lost. If the fiddle gets the async function resolves in order, what's wrong? O_o

Comment: Text and fiddle updated to more clearly show the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `map()` on its own since you should be able to handle the resolution of the previous Promise. There was a good [example of using `reduce()` for sequencing Promises in an Google article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises#creating_a_sequence).

[`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) allowes you to "chain" the Promise of the current item with the Promise of the previous item. To start the chain, you pass a resolved Promise as initial value to `reduce()`.

Assume `l` as the input data and `async()` to modify the data asynchronously. It will just multiply the input data by 10.

```
var l = [1, 2, 3 ,4];

function async(data) {
    console.log("call with ", data);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => { console.log("resolve", data); resolve(data * 10); }, 1000);
    });
}
```

This is the relevant code (its function is inline-commented)

```
// Reduce the inout data into a Promise chain
l.reduce(function(sequencePromise, inValue) {
    /* For the first item sequencePromise will resolve with the value of the 
     * Promise.resolve() call passed to reduce(), for all other items it's 
     * the previous promise that was returned by the handler in the next line.
     */
    return sequencePromise.then(function(responseValues) {
        /* responseValues is an array, initially it's the empty value passed to
         * reduce(), for subsequent calls it's the concat()enation result.
         *
         * Call async with the current inValue.
         */
        return async(inValue).then((outValue) => {
            /* and concat the outValue to the 
             * sequence array and return it. The next item will receive that new 
             * array as value to the resolver of sequencePromise.
             */
            return responseValues.concat([outValue]);
        });
    });
}, Promise.resolve([]) /* Start with a resolved Promise */ ).then(function(responseValues){
    console.log(responseValues);
});
```

The console will finally log

```
Array [ 10, 20, 30, 40 ]
```

Comment: `You can't use map()` - you actually can - https://jsfiddle.net/jaromanda/d6qwf1x4/ - in some ways less elegant, but not unpossible :p

Comment: Well yes you're right - but you can't use `map()` on its own without surrounding code. It's the same with the `forEach()` code behind that Google dev link, the code's just a bit less elegant.

Comment: I like the substance of this answer but honestly, the code almost unreadable, and the comments actually make it worse.  I'm accepting it (because it's right) but I put a far briefer version in [my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41908707/238884).

Comment: First, thanks for accepting my answer! The rationale behind the comments were to explain the function of the code. While you might understand its function without the comments other users coming across this post may appreciate the explanation.

Comment: I hate to criticize somebody who did exactly what I asked, out of the goodness of his heart, but you did also commit the Original Sin of commenting, repeating the code in comments.  This is one line: `return responseValues.concat([outValue]);`.  Here is your comment on the line: "concat the outValue to the sequence array and return it."  Please don't do that.  Not here, not in your real life.   Code says what; comments are for why. Secondarily, don't use "value" as part of a variable name: all variables point to values.

Answer (score 1):

```
const mapAsync = (l, f) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const results = [];
  const recur = () => {
    if (results.length < l.length) {
      f(l[results.length]).then(v => {
        results.push(v);
        recur();
      }).catch(reject);
    } else {
      resolve(results);
    }
  };
  recur();
});
```

**EDIT:**  Tholle's remark led me to this far more elegant and (I hope) [anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)-free solution:

```
const mapAsync = (l, f) => {
  const recur = index =>
    index < l.length
      ? f(l[index]).then(car => recur(index + 1).then(cdr => [car].concat(cdr)))
      : Promise.resolve([]);

  return recur(0);
};
```

**FURTHER EDIT**:

The appropriately named Try-catch-finally suggest an even neater implementation, using `reduce`.  Further improvements welcome.

```
const mapAsync2 = (l, f) =>
  l.reduce(
    (promise, item) =>
      promise.then(results => 
        f(item).then(result => results.concat([result]))),
    Promise.resolve([])
  );
```

Comment: I like your solution. I asked [**this similar question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31575001/looping-with-promises) a while back.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than coding the logic yourself I'd suggest using async.js for this. Since you're dealing with promises use the promisified async-q library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-q (note: the documentation is much easier to read on github:https://github.com/dbushong/async-q)

What you need is `mapSeries`:

```
async.mapSeries(l,f).then(function (result) {
    // result is guaranteed to be in the correct order
});
```

Note that the arguments passed to `f` is hardcoded as `f(item, index, arr)`. If your function accept different arguments you can always wrap it up in another function to reorder the arguments:

```
async.mapSeries(l,function(x,idx,l){
    return f(x); // must return a promise
}).then(function (result) {
    // result is guaranteed to be in the correct order
});
```

You don't need to do this if your function accepts only one argument.

---

You can also just use the original callback based async.js:

```
async.mapSeries(l,function(x,idx,l){
    function (cb) {
        f(x).then(function(result){
            cb(null, result); // pass result as second argument,
                              // first argument is error
        });
    }
},function (err, result) {
    // result is guaranteed to be in the correct order
});
```

Comment: FTFD: "This code only works on node; I've not bothered to make it browser-safe in any way." My need for this function is mostly theoretically, and entirely in React Native.

Comment: @Malvolio: You can always use the original `async.js` which runs in the browser just fine

Comment: callbacks drool, promises rule.